# teminate subprocess.call( 'python script") and continure with next test script query

Tags: python, subprocess

I have written this demo script to ask my question on `subprocess.call()`.
I am trying to run python test scripts one after another. However in this scenario when one of the test aborts due to invalid test condition, I want to terminate `subprocess.call()`. and move on to next test script. I have read through other queries but couldn't find sufficient explanation. Appreciate any suggestion or help in this matter. Below are demo files.

File1:  `listscripts.py` -> this file list all tests from a folder and runs them using subprocess.call()

```
import os
from subprocess import *
import sys,os,time

Lib_Path = "C:\\Demo\\question"
sys.path.append(Lib_Path)
import globalsvar  # has a global variable

list = os.listdir("C:\\Demo\\question\\scripts")  # this has 3 example basic script

for testscripts in list:

    aborttest = globalsvar.aborttestcall  # when it encounters invalid condition from testscript1thru3 call() should terminate and go to next test

    while not aborttest:

           Desttestresultpath = os.path.join('C:/Demo/question/scripts',pyscripts)

           call(["python",Desttestresultpath]) #calls individual scripts

           aborttest = True
exit(1)
```

File2: `globalsvar.py ( aborttestcall = False )`

`testscript1.py`, `testscript2.py` and `testscript3.py` -> has some print statments placed in `C:/Demo/question/scripts`

`testscript1.py` and `testscript3.py`:

```
import sys,os,time

Lib_Path = "C:\\Demo\\question"

sys.path.append(Lib_Path)

import globalsvar

print "Start of Test\n"
print "testing stdout prints --1"

time.sleep(1)


globalsvar.aborttestcall = False


print "testing stdout prints --2"

time.sleep(1)

print "testing stdout prints --3"

time.sleep(1)
```

`testscript2.py`:

```
import sys,os,time

Lib_Path = "C:\\Demo\\question"

sys.path.append(Lib_Path)

import globalsvar

print "Start of Test\n"
print "testing stdout prints --1"

time.sleep(1)


globalsvar.aborttestcall = True


print "testing stdout prints --2"

time.sleep(1)

print "testing stdout prints --3"

time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I may didn't unterstand correctly. If you want to run these scripts one by another, why don't you exit the childs on failure but use such a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your scripts (among different possibilities) like this:

```
import subprocess
import os

for file_item in os.listdir('scripts'):
   script = os.sep.join(['scripts', file_item])
   return_value = subprocess.call(['python', script])
   print "OUTPUT: " + str(return_value)
```

while your inner scripts can exit their process with an exit code that you can evaluate on your calling process.

```
import time
import sys

print "Doing subprocess testing stuff"
time.sleep(2)
print "Doing more subprocess testing stuff"

# simulate error
time.sleep(2)
print "Error, jump out of the process"
sys.exit(1)

# finish
time.sleep(2)
print "done"

# this can be left out since it is called implicitely
# on successful step out of a process
# sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: @smi If my answer helped you, it would be nice if you mark it as solution.

Comment: :) . how to mark it as solution. still new to using stack overflow features.

Comment: @smi Refer [here on how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Basically click on the tick beneath the answer's score till it turns green ;)